# javascript, ajax, jquery and php

Tags: jquery

I wanted to know how to get variables on other page using ajax.
I have the following code:

this is checkedin.php

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "event.php",
            data: "name=John&location=Boston"
    }).send();
</script>
<?php
 header("refresh: 5;buttons.php");
?>
```

The 'checkedin.php' page is again returned to the first page by a redirect.

I want to get the name and location on 'event.php' page. All the files are '*.php' files. I am not able to get anything on 'event.php'

I am visiting the page 'event.php' in a new tab and trying to print the value using the following syntax:

this is event.php

```
    session_start();
echo count($_POST);
print_r($_POST);
echo $_POST['name']."<br/>";
    echo $_POST['location']."<br/>";
```

Is there anything that I am missing?? I haven't used ajax before...

Answer (score 0):

You can't view the view the ajax variable on other page which is open in new tab. if you want that your page automatically know when the variable are passed to it. then you need to use reverse ajax, [Ape (Ajax Push Engine)](http://www.ape-project.org/)

But If you want to post the variable to another page and want to get the request back on the same page. then you can use [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), json.

First You need to decide what is your exact requirements. then you chose either ajax or reverse ajax. 
example of ajax

```
//page1.php
bodyContent = $.ajax({
      url: "page2.php",
      global: false,
      type: "POST",
      data: ({var1 : this.getAttribute('var1')}),
      dataType: "json",
      async:false,
      success: function(data){
                alert(data.myvar);
      }
   }
).responseJson;




// page2.php

session_start();
print json_encode(array('myvar' => $_REQUEST['var1']));
```

Comment: well actually the requirement is simple. I have a login page where the student logs in.

I have a queue which shows the current student in the queue.
So when a new student student logs in there is an entry in the database and what I am looking for is to update the queue page without sending any request to the server.

I do not wish to use polling and comet as was wondering if I can do it with Jquery events PHP and ajax.